# Castle Windsor: Register by convention, open generics

Tags: castle-windsor, castle-windsor-3

I have an interface like so:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T>
```

I have a base class like so:

```
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

I have a class like so:

```
public class AGenericRepository<T> : GenericRepository<T> where T : class
```

Without convention, I successfully registered like so:

```
container.Register(
    Component.For(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).ImplementedBy(typeof(AGenericRepository<>))
);
```

I can successfully resolve an object like so:

```
var robot = container.Resolve<GenericRepository<Android>>();
```

However, when trying to register by convention like so:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .BasedOn(typeof(GenericRepository<>))
                            .WithService.Base());
```

I cannot resolve as I did above.  What gives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing an answer since this may be too long (and codeful) for a comment.

Given the following code:

```
public interface IGenericRepository<T> {}
public abstract class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepository<T> where T : class {}
public class AGenericRepository<T> : GenericRepository<T> where T : class {}
public class AInstance: AGenericRepository<string>{}
```

this registration works fine for me:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof (GenericRepository<>)).WithServiceBase());
var result = container.Resolve<GenericRepository<string>>();
```

I have a feeling that we are lacking some information regarding what classes are registered.

---

EDIT: in the proposed code apparently the abstract base class acts as a stop gap to determine what the base service is. If you use the following registration the resolution works:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof (GenericRepository<>)).WithServiceAllInterfaces());
var result = container.Resolve<IGenericRepository<string>>();
```

However the resolution against the `GenericRepository` doesn't seem to work because it is not registered as a resolution component in castle. If you want to self register components you can describe it directly:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof (GenericRepository<>)).WithServices(typeof(GenericRepository<>)));
var result = container.Resolve<GenericRepository<string>>();
// result is AGenericRepository<string>
```

Comment: Why do you have that AInstance class?  Remove that class and tell us if you can still resolve.

Comment: Because you cannot resolve a component that has no implementation. But now it's clearer what you're getting at. I'll delete this answer if I can't enrich it

Comment: The implementation of the class AGenericRepository<T> provides implementation for any closed type such as AGenericRepository<Android>.  My question also included the one to one registration and resolve code that works.  What I'm asking is if there is a way to register by convention in this scenario.

Comment: I am new to Windsor and I read most of the Wiki.  As a matter of fact I just did a search on the Wiki and found no mentions of the function WithServices().  Where does one go to find the most comprehensive documentation for Castle Windsor?

Comment: Nice answer Samy. Just came back to say try: `container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn(typeof(GenericRepository<>)).WithService.Select(new[] { typeof(GenericRepository<>) }))`

Comment: Thanks Samy.  Thanks for your help also Phil.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Just had a look at the source code and unfortunately `Base()` has different handling for interfaces as opposed to abstract classes. It does not properly handle completely open registrations like this. But this workaround is straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

`DefaultInterfaces()` only registers interfaces with a matching name.

> Matching names, means that the implementing class contains in its name
>   the name of the interface (without the I on the front).

http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx

Comment: Good catch.  That was just a mistake in the middle of me trying different things.  I was originally using Base() but WithService.Base() doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes there does seem to be an issue there when you use an abstract class as opposed to an interface. But why do you want to use conventions? You have one open generic service and one open generic implementation. Your first registration approach works fine.

Comment: It would be nice if I can register by convention because if I have generic implementations for NHibernate, EntityFrameWork, Memory (for testing) etc, that they'd all be registered automatically as they're added.  It would also be nice to know that it is possible.  Furthermore, this is just a single situation.  What if in another situation there is the potential to have quite a few implementations?  That's the whole basis for Registering By Convention.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look at the code. Out of curiosity could you post the place in the code where the handling of open abstract classes occur?

Comment: Away from PC now but from memory it was something to do with a workaround for a CLR bug in the service descriptor code...